# Magento Enterprise: catalog_product_attribute not reindexed on product save

Tags: product, product-attribute, layered-navigation, reindex, ee-1.13.0.2

I'm using Magento ee 1.13.0.2 and discovering the next problem:
I have some of the attributes used in layered navigation - color and size. When I add a new product (simple one) and save it - product successfully appears in catalog, however if I click on product's size/color in layered nav - product is not found. If I go to index management page, I see "Product attributes" has mode "Update on Save" and status "Reindex required". If I reindex manually - everything works fine, product can be found by color/size now.

But this is not something I expect - if there is "Update on Save", index should be updated automatically on product save, without manual reindex, right?

Future tests shows me, that Product attribute index becomes "Reindex Required" always, when I save product even without changes..

I tried to debug reindex on product save, and it appears that queries, which fill `catalog_product_index_eav`, `catalog_product_index_eav_tmp` tables are all part of one big transaction, which starts on "product save before" and ends on "product save after". Of course, when I debug queries which are generating data for index_eav tables, they return empty results, because product doesn't even exists in `catalog_product_entity` table...

So, for now I stuck on this, had any one the same issue?

Comment: we are having exactly the same issue in 1.13.0.2. This not only happens when we add a new product, but when we update an existing product (let's say we update it's price) The "Product Attributes" index asks for "Reindex Required" Any help will be appretiated

Comment: We are having the same issue and have traced the invalidating back to the event `cataloginventory_stock_partial_reindex` but even removing this event will mean that the data has not been indexed.

Comment: So useful information about indexing in ee113 at http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee113-indexing

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that partial reindex was not implemented for product attributes and tags indices.

It is still persistent in 1.14.0.1. You may find more details in [my question here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/29385/93). Also some comments are also quite interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could solve this was:

```
$product
    ->setForceReindexRequired(true)
    ->setIsChangedCategories(true);

    Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction(
                    $product,
                    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
                    Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE
                );

    $process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_attribute');
                $process->reindexEverything();
```

I know isn't the best, but is the only that works for me.

Comment: It would be useful to know where have you added this code.