# Why is there no partial re-indexing for EAV and tags?

Tags: indexing, eav, bug, tags, ee-1.13.1.0

This question was puzzling me for quite a while.

Why is the <s>improvement</s> bugfix introduced in Magento 1.13.x.x called partial re-indexing not covering "Product Attributes" and "Tags Aggregation Data" indexers? Why do these two have to be re-indexed manually?

To my opinion EAV index is one of the most critical. Not having a partial re-indexing for it means that after each sale (and some people have them) the index is invalidated which means the layered navigation is not valid anymore which results in inconsistent data display and loss of sales.

Am I missing something obvious?

**Update:**

So here is the description of this **bug**. Once the sale is made and product goes out of stock the layered navigation reflects the changes for products attributes only for simple products but not for configurables (have not tested bundles and grouped).

So let's assume in your catalog you have a configurable product like t-shirt available in different sizes and "Size" attribute is "Filterable (with results)". Then in a layered navigation of appropriate category or search results you will have the sizes section where all **available** sizes are listed. If after one of the sales, a particular size goes out of stock you would expect it to disappear from layered navigation. This doesn't happen unless you refresh attributes index and flush blocks cache.

This bug is really critical. It's a two way threat. First, the end customer who sees his size in a layered navigation and then sees that it is actually not available will leave your shop in frustration. Even worse thing is once the product is back in stock it will not be visible in layered navigation, so the end customer will not be able to purchase it. So it's hard to underestimate the amount of revenue losses.

Comment: Not sure, but isn't the layered navigation joined with the stock index, which has this bugfix? So why would you need to reindex then after an order has been placed?

Comment: We run out of time to implement those two and they were not critical from the performance standpoint which was the main driving factor for the changes. If you see inconsistent data can you report to support? Maybe there is a patch for that.

Comment: @TobiasZander can you please tell me the patch number?

Comment: @PiotrKaminski this is sad but you can safely post it as an answer as it of course explains everything.

Comment: @TobiasZander just checked on the clean Magento installation w/ a sample data. Please see the update to the question.

Comment: @Tim is this the same/similar to http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/12800/158

Comment: @DavidManners this is definitely connected however the loose is different

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly do the index fixes in 1.14.1.0 fix this? It says they do but would be helpful to be updated in your question if so. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ee1.14_release-notes.html#ee1141-patches-connect-index

Comment: This issue is for an Enterprise Edition store with a valid Magento Enterprise Edition license, please login to the Magento account linked to the license and open a support ticket for further assistance.

To open a support ticket
1) Login to your Magento Commerce account https://www.magentocommerce.com/
2) Go to Support > Open a Ticket
3) Click on Open New Ticket
4) Enter the required information and click Submit

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about EE

Comment: I don't think a question being about EE is a reason to close it as many dev's out there have access to EE. I do see a reason in closing this as this seems a core bug? So it's up to Magento to solve and not us...

Comment: Woah. EE is a perfectly valid version of Magento with a lot of developers (as evidenced by the number of votes this thing has).

Comment: Since when EE questions are disallowed? There are about 2K EE question at this website. Will you close all of them or only those you don't like?

Comment: "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about EE" - Not cool

Comment: @7ochem right, this being a core bug made it for me off topic since there was little reason an answer would ever be posted here

Comment: Hehehe, @SanderMangel is going *through the mangel (mangle)* :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To not let this question hang at the top of the unanswered queue forever, here's the official answer to "WHY" again:

> **We run out of time to implement those two and they were not critical from the performance standpoint which was the main driving factor for the changes**. If you see inconsistent data can you report to support? Maybe there is a patch for that.

<sup>*– Piotr Kaminski Jul 18 '14 at 17:38*</sup>