# Reindex Required on Product Save

Tags: magento-1.7, indexing, reindex

Every time when I save a product with changes or without changes following index required reindex:

```
Product Attributes
Product Prices
Stock Status
```

All Index mode is set to " Update on Save ". I have checked the exception and system log, there is no error related to this.

Can you help me to guide how can I debug this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this with my own webshop when building it.

For me the problem was caching.

So if you have a live host: 
Login and clear the host's cache.

Clear the Magento cache on the back-end.

And clear the var/cache folder on your FTP.

Maybe it solves your problem, else I don't know. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm researching the same issue. It's a know and common problem with partial indexing: see [Magento Enterprise: catalog_product_attribute not reindexed on product save](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12800/magento-enterprise-catalog-product-attribute-not-reindexed-on-product-save)